# Function to normalise string file paths

Tags: python

Is there a Python function that can normalise string file paths OR compare string file paths?

Ie a function like the following(which I made up):

```
norm_path = os.normalise("C:\\abc/def/hij\\")
print(norm_path) # c:\abc\def\hij

# I'm looking for a function that converts all "/" to "\\", converts to lowercase
# and removes trailing "\\" or "/" chars so I can compare strings
```

Before I write my own function I want to see if theres already a function that does this so I dont reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath("C:\\abc/def/hij\\")))
c:\abc\def\hij
```